# Riemann Mapping Theorem in Higher Dimensions for Continuous funcions

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is there any analogue for Riemann Mapping Theorem(!) in higher dimensions?

Or a much simpler question, is it true that every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with zero homology in dimensions 1 and 2 is homeomorphic to interior of the unit disk? What about contractible subsets?

Comment: The Riemann mapping theorem is about conformal maps, not just homeomorphisms. I think you need to narrow down your question or define it more precisely

Comment: Yes I know the Riemann Mapping Theorem speaks about conformal maps, but here I am just interested in continuous case.

Comment: A Riemann mapping theorem that is not about conformal maps should not be called a Riemann mapping theorem.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. For example, [Alexander horned sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere) divides $S^3$ into two regions, both with trivial homology (Poincare duality), but the $\pi_1$ is nontrivial.

Answer (score 2):

The Whitehead manifold is a counterexample: it is a contractible subset of ${\mathbb R}^3$, but not homeomorphic to the open unit disk.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold

Answer (score 2):

Even in the holomorphic category, Riemann Mapping Theorem fails in high dimensions. For example, the unit ball is not biholomorphic to polydisks.